# Jquery.getJSON can't get all the data to display

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

So I'm rather new to JSON generally, and am beginning get a reasonable understanding of the file. I'm trying to populate my web page with data form my JSON file using .getJSON, I've got as far as managing to populate the page with one lot of information. However I'm struggling to 
a: get the other information to populate the page 
b: display all the data at the same time.

here is the getjson function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('js/jobs.json', function (result) {
        result.jobs.map(function (v) {
            $('#title').html(v.title);
            $('#info1').html(v.path +' '+ v.type + ' ' + v.location + ' ' + v.closingDate + ' ' + v.skills);
            $('#info2').html(v.salary.lower +' '+  v.salary.upper + ' '+ v.employer.name + ' ' + v.employer.href + ' ' + v.employer.logo);

        }); 
    });
});
```

Which I know is probably fairly crudely done, but I will fix that.

And here is the JSON file

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "title": "Graduate IT Development Programme #1",
            "path": "/path/to/job",
            "type": "Graduate job",
            "location": [
                "North West",
                "North East"
            ],
            "closingDate": "20/05/2014",
            "continuous": false,
            "skills": [
                "HTML",
                "CSS",
                "JavaScript",
                "Java",
                "CI",
                "Testing"
            ],
            "contract": "Permanent",
            "salary": {
                "lower": 14501,
                "upper": 17000,
                "currency": "£"
            },
            "employer": {
                "name": "Mercer",
                "href": "/path/to/employer",
                "logo": "img/mercer-logo.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Web Developer",
            "path": "/path/to/job",
            "type": "Graduate job",
            "location": ["Greater London"],
            "continuous": true,
            "skills": [
                "HTML",
                "CSS",
                "JavaScript"
            ],
            "salary": {
                "lower": 16000,
                "upper": 21000,
                "currency": "€"
            },
            "employer": {
                "name": "FDM plc",
                "href": "/path/to/employer",
                "logo": "img/fdm-logo.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Front-end Web Developer",
            "path": "/path/to/job",
            "type": "Graduate scheme",
            "location": ["Greater London"],
            "closingDate": "20/04/2014",
            "continuous": false,
            "skills": [
                "HTML",
                "CSS",
                "Java",
                "Testing"
            ],
            "salary": {
                "lower": 17001,
                "upper": 19500,
                "currency": "£"
            },
            "employer": {
                "name": "British Airways plc",
                "href": "/path/to/employer",
                "logo": "img/british-airways-logo.png"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The output I'm getting is displaying the last array of data (with the title "front-end developer") I have everything displaying, but I am struggling to get the other arrays of data to display, I've gone as far as creating a separate function and pretty much hard coding it and I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` replaces the current content. Use `.append()` instead.